# Get part of JSON and save it to JSONArray

Tags: android, json

The result of echo json_encode($response) is

```
{"error":false,"message":"Success","neededData":[{"column1":1,"column2":2,"column3":3},{"column1":4,"column2":5,"column3":6}]}
```

What I need is only

```
[{"column1":1,"column2":2,"column3":3},{"column1":4,"column2":5,"column3":6}] and save it to a JSONArray array.


JSONObject userJson = obj.getJSONObject("neededData");
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(userJson);
```

doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 try {
        JSONObject  jsonObject = new JSONObject("YOUR RESPONSE STRING FROM OF JSON OBJECT");
        JSONArray neededData = jsonObject.getJSONArray("neededData");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

neededData is an json Array and not a json Object 
your are doing it wrong

```
    JSONObject JjsonResponse = new JSONObject(yourresponce);
    JSONArray data= jsonResponse.getJSONArray("neededData ");
```

Answer (score 0):

I would be code like as below.

```
String strjsonobj='{"error":false,"message":"Success","neededData":[{"column1":1,"column2":2,"column3":3},{"column1":4,"column2":5,"column3":6}]}';


try {
    JSONObject  jsonObject = new JSONObject(strjsonobj);
    JSONArray neededData = jsonObject.getJSONArray("neededData");
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```